# Mathematica Map question

Tags: dictionary, wolfram-mathematica

Original question:

I know Mathematica has a built in map(f, x), but what does this function look like?  I know you need to look at every element in the list.

Any help or suggestions?

Edit (by Jefromi, pieced together from Mike's comments):

I am working on a program what needs to move through a list like the Map, but I am not allowed to use it. I'm not allowed to use Table either; I need to move through the list without help of another function. I'm working on a recursive version, I have an empty list one down, but moving through a list with items in it is not working out. Here is my first case: `newMap[#, {}] = {}` (the map of an empty list is just an empty list)

Comment: What do you mean by "what does this function look like"? I assume you're asking about `Map`; have you looked at [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html)? Is there something there that confuses you?

Comment: I'm not sure what your looking for.  Are you looking for the signature of `Map` (argument layout), how it operates, or how it's implemented?

Comment: I'm looking for how it operates, how to recursively move through a list in mathematica, and especially what is the first argument in Map, how to implement if I was written that myself  I know Map(__, List)  what would I put in the first bracket?

Comment: "how to recursively move through a list in mathematica": in general, the answer is not to reinvent it. Use Map, or MapAt or MapIndexed or whatever's appropriate. Do you have a specific task, similar to Map, that you're trying to accomplish? Or are you just curious about implementation?

Comment: or is the first argument an #, an annoymous function

Comment: I am working on a program what needs to move through a list like the Map, but I am not allowed to use it.  I am trying to figure out how it is implemented

Comment: @Mike: Aha! Generic advice for asking questions: ask about what you really want to do.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use that either, I need to move through the list without help of another function, i'm working on a recursive version, I have an empty list one down, but moving through a list with items in it is not working out

Comment: @Mike: You can't possibly do it without using *any* functions; everything's a function, even `First`, `Last`, and `Part`. If you could edit your question to state exactly what it is you need to do and what your restrictions are, we can provide helpful answers, instead of trying to guess. Also, if your comment refers to an answer, you can comment on the answer itself, rather than your question.

Comment: I have to create a version of map, I'm attempting recursion and here is my first case:     newMap[#, {}] = {}   (the map of an empty list is just an empty list)  what to do if items in list?

Comment: @Jefromi: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812) but, Mike, please follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), including stating specific restrictions, what you've tried so far, and what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: @Roger: My bad. I'll edit something into the question. @Mike: Please, please, edit things into your question instead of adding them to the comments. It's a pain to have to read through all these to figure out what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 6):

I posted a recursive solution but then decided to delete it, since from the comments this sounds like a homework problem, and I'm normally a teach-to-fish person.

You're on the way to a recursive solution with your definition `newMap[f_, {}] := {}`.

Mathematica's pattern-matching is your friend. Consider how you might implement the definition for `newMap[f_, {e_}]`, and from there, `newMap[f_, {e_, rest___}]`.

One last hint: once you can define that last function, you don't actually need the case for `{e_}`.

**UPDATE**:

Based on your comments, maybe this example will help you see how to apply an arbitrary function:

```
func[a_, b_] := a[b]

In[4]:= func[Abs, x]
Out[4]= Abs[x]
```

**SOLUTION**

Since the OP caught a fish, so to speak, (congrats!) here are two recursive solutions, to satisfy the curiosity of any onlookers. This first one is probably what I would consider "idiomatic" Mathematica:

```
map1[f_, {}] := {}
map1[f_, {e_, rest___}] := {f[e], Sequence@@map1[f,{rest}]}
```

Here is the approach that does not leverage pattern matching quite as much, which is basically what the OP ended up with:

```
map2[f_, {}] := {}
map2[f_, lis_] :=  {f[First[lis]], Sequence@@map2[f, Rest[lis]]}
```

The `{f[e], Sequence@@map[f,{rest}]}` part can be expressed in a variety of equivalent ways, for example:

- `Prepend[map[f, {rest}], f[e]]`
- `Join[{f[e]}, map[f, {rest}]` (@Mike used this method)
- `Flatten[{{f[e]}, map[f, {rest}]}, 1]`

I'll leave it to the reader to think of any more, and to ponder the performance implications of most of those =)

Finally, for fun, here's a procedural version, even though writing it made me a little nauseous: ;-)

```
map3[f_, lis_] :=
 (* copy lis since it is read-only *)
 Module[{ret = lis, i},
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[lis], i++,
   ret[[i]] = f[lis[[i]]]
   ];
  ret
  ]
```

Comment: +1, for the pattern, `{e_, rest___}`, alone. I wish I thought in those terms more than I do. And, no extra functions required.

Comment: +1; the elegance of pattern-matching reminds me how much I miss Mathematica.

Comment: I can conceive of one, minor, advantage to using `First` and `Rest` over this:  the variable `rest` does not refer to a list.  But, that is easily overcome, and if you need to avoid external functions as much as possible, nothing beats patterns.

Comment: Lets say that you do this newmap[Abs, List] and that gives you the absolute value of that list.  Instead of putting Abs, I need the ability to use other functions is this acceptable newmap[#, List]

Comment: And what does f_ mean?  I know that _ pattern matching

Comment: `_` is [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html), and matches any expression. `f_` effectively just assigns whatever was matched to a local variable `f` in the function definition. It might be helpful to read the ["Introduction to Patterns"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html) tutorial.

Comment: I want to use my newmap function to apply the Abs or another function to the list, is this acceptable?  newmap[#, List] := First[List] + Rest[List];  How can I apply the Abs to this function?

Comment: The built-in `Map` will map over any head so maybe something more like `newMap[f_, lst_[a_, b__]] := ...` would be more appropriate.  There's one last trick that can be used in this method, which is the use of Sequence@@, which can be abbreviated/obfuscated to ##&@@

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not following, is an anonymous function not the way to go here?

Comment: Also, +1 for the fishing lesson!

Comment: Thanks, let me see what I can do with this now

Comment: maps[fun_, x_] := fun[Head[x]] +  fun[Rest[x]]

Comment: I'm trying to do this maps[abs, list] and list consists of {1, -2, 3}  Any help on why this isn't working!

Comment: `+` does not join lists, it is always an arithmetic operator in Mathematica. Suggested reading: ["List Manipulation"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html)

Comment: I meant to add that you're getting much closer! Also, `Head[f[1,2,3]]` gives `f`, so `Head` is not the right function to extract the _first_ element of an expression...

Comment: maps[fun_, x_] := Join[fun[First[x]], fun[Rest[x]]]  => but First does not give back a list, I can not seem to find a condition that will join the first item in the list to the rest of the list

Comment: Very close now! `fun[Rest[x]]` will work in some cases, but not for the right reasons in the frame of this problem.

Comment: maps[fun_, x_] := Join[fun[{First[x]}], fun[Rest[x]]] => what do you mean this won't work for the frame of the problem?

Comment: Some functions in Mathematica are "`Listable`", meaning they automatically map themselves over any list arguments. Compare the results of evaluating `Abs[{1, -1, 2}]` vs. `f[{1, 2, 3}]`. If your solution is correct, `maps[f, {1,2,3}]` will give `{f[1],f[2],f[3]}`, but I believe it will instead output `{f[1], f[{2,3}]}` and probably some errors.

Comment: I get this output mymap[f, {1, 2, 3}], but i'm not seeing how to correct this, any further help, please!  I do see i'm getting different output though

Comment: Is there a certain function to use instead of Rest?

Comment: In your function, `Rest[x]` correctly gives the "rest" of the list, and then you need to map `fun` over it, and join it to the first part. But, you already have a function to map `fun` over a list, so...

Comment: newmap[fun_, x_] := Join[fun[{First[x]}], newmap[fun, fun[Rest[x]]]] => recursion is not really my strong point, is this kind of what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you're now very, very close, but you have one too many calls to `fun` there.

Comment: I am not seeing it, could you show me which extra call your talking about, I kept getting recursion limit exceeded

Comment: `newmap[fun, fun[Rest[x]]]` -- you are mapping `fun` over `fun[Rest[x]]`. As for the recursion limit, any recursive function needs a base case. Consider what happens when `x` is just a single-element list `{a}`, and then what happens when it is empty, `{}`.

Comment: ewmap[fun_, x_] := Join[fun[{First[x]}], newmap[fun, Rest[x]]] => thats what I have but get this for output Join[f[{1}], f[{2}], f[{3}], {}]

Comment: How can you make that a list other then adding { } around it, I don't see any other options?  Is there a function that does that, maybe i'm missing.

Comment: You have the right idea with `fun[{First[x]}]`, but the brackets are in the wrong place.

Comment: newmap[fun_, x_] := Join[func[Take[x, 1]], newmap[fun, Rest[x]]], does this look closer? still not doing newmap[f, {1, 2, 3}]

Comment: Thank you so much I finally got it

Comment: Great, congrats! I updated my answer again with the solution(s) I had in mind as we were going along...

Comment: @Michael Pilat, I wish I could upvote this again.  Nice patient walk through from a clear starting point.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you posed in the comments, the first argument in `Map` is a function that accepts a single argument.  This can be a pure function, or the name of a function that already only accepts a single argument like

```
In[1]:=f[x_]:= x + 2
       Map[f, {1,2,3}]
Out[1]:={3,4,5}
```

As to how to replace `Map` with a recursive function of your own devising ...  Following Jefromi's example, I'm not going to give to much away, as this is homework.  But, you'll obviously need some way of operating on a piece of the list while keeping the rest of the list intact for the recursive part of you map function.  As he said, [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html?q=Part&lang=en) is a good starting place, but I'd look at some of the other functions it references and see if they are more useful, like `First` and `Rest`.  Also, I can see where `Flatten` would be useful.  Finally, you'll need a way to end the recursion, so learning how to constrain patterns may be useful.  Incidentally, this can be done in one or two lines depending on if you create a second definition for your map (the easier way), or not.

**Hint**:  Now that you have your end condition, you need to answer three questions:

1. how do I extract a single element from my list,
2. how do I reference the remaining elements of the list, and
3. how do I put it back together?

It helps to think of a single step in the process, and what do you need to accomplish in that step.

Comment: Given that table is disallowed, First/Rest are definitely nice idioms here.