# Correct User Defined Version of Map Function in Mathematica?

Tags: functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to create a user defined version of the `Map[]` function in Mathematica and I'm running into a few problems.

Here is what I have so far:

```
map[x_, s_List] := mapAux[x, s, {}];
mapAux[x, s, {}] :=  Append[{}, First[s]];
mapAux[x, Rest[s], {}];
```

I'm trying to use it as

```
map[# + 1 &, {3, 6, 8}]
```

but this gives a mysterious error beside the output:

```
 Rest::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Rest[s].

 mapAux[#1 + 1 &, {3, 6, 8}, {}]
```

The ideal result  would be `{4,7,9}`. I researched the "Nonatomic expression" error and I'm not sure what it means. I'm passing a list to it, but it's just exploding!

Comment: You might find my previous answer (and the comments on it) to the more-or-less exact same question informative: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/4126874/272923](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4126874/272923)

Comment: I wonder if some teacher out there is collecting Map clones

Comment: @belisarius I wonder if the students fail for not displaying sufficient google-fu?

Comment: It's simpler to test something like this with a function that won't evaluate away, so you can really be sure you got the result you expect: `Map[f, {1,2,3}]` returns `{f[1],f[2],f[3]}`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `s` or `x` as variables, so it's just seeing `s` (which is an atomic expression) rather than a list.  You're definition needs to be `mapAux[x_, s_, {}]:=...`, which will make `x` and `s` take the values of the passed parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed that, but now it's just outputting one of the list items such as {3} and it's not even adding it. Does the append need to be fixed?

Comment: Well you never actually apply x to First[s], so all it's doing is appending the first element of s to an empty list and returning that.  You're not doing any iterating or application.

Comment: @jackRAY, this has been answered before.  You should check out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4126874/272923.